# How to create VoIP Notification provisioning profile?

Tags: php, ios, iphone, voip

For VoIP notification i am not able to create a production provisioning profile. Because every time my VoIP certificate not came in the provisioning creating list.

Comment: Please trim down your problem to "What is exactly the problem you are facing there"

Comment: @Talha , the problem is i am not able to create a provisioning profile with the use of VoIP enabled certificate.